# How to filter out porn results using the YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

There is a lot of porn on YouTube. We want to filter out those results when using the YouTube search API, but the only way to do it is to use `safeSearch=strict`.

One problem with this is that it filters out songs that contain swear words.
We don't mind adult language, it's porn we want to filter out.

The frustrating thing about this is that if I use `safeSearch=moderate` or `safeSearch=none`, there is absolutely NOTHING in the data response from YouTube that tells me if a particular video is adult or not.
The "media$rating" is basically non-existent in most cases.

So how is that YouTube knows to filter out the media when using strict mode, but doesn't know to tell me that it's adult when I'm using moderate mode?

To reiterate, we want to filter out porn, but not swear words. How do you do this when the YouTube data API is unreliable to a fault?

Comment: Porn: you know it when you see it!

Comment: `safeSearch` is fine, words can hurt more than a porn.

Comment: Try the search query parameter with which you can disregard videos containing certain words-https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#qsp

Comment: It looks like this is based on the restriction to locale, that's what determines what content is strict/moderate/none. You may want to check your locale/restriction setting and see what content falls into what category.